# Getting version of uninstalled Python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, version

I have just joined a project that defined the version string in `src/__init__.py` like so

```
#src/__init__.py
version = '0.0.7'
```

and the application in the same directory

```
#src/acme.py
...
# get version here
```

I'd like to get the version string in the application, but everything I've tried has failed I suspect because much of the advise out here is geared towards installed modules, whereas the acme module is not installed.

Comment: `import src` then `print(src.version)`?

Comment: Actually the working directory is src and `from . import version` generates the error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

Comment: Of course it does. You can only use relative imports within a package. You don't have a package, from the POV of the import system. You said you don't want to "install" this, so, just move the working directory to `../src`